# Change subfigure numbering

Tags: subfloats, subfig

I would like to change the subfigure numbering (a), (b), (c), (d),...
to something like (a), (b1), (b2), (c), (d1), (d2), (d3), (e1), (e2) but cannot find a solution to this... I want some related figures share the same letter. Can LaTeX allow DIY numbering?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how LaTeX is supposed to know when to use a single letter and when to use a letter/digit combination. Please also tell us which package you use to create subfigures: `subcaption`, `subfig`, or something else.

Comment: You could create subsubfigures to distinguish between (b1) and (b).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423580/how-to-label-subset-of-figures-as-subfigures-and-include-an-overall-caption (second solution).