# Subfigures of subfigures

Tags: subfloats

I want to create subfigure of subfigures in latex. A verbose example is below:

Given two set group, e.g. felines and canines, I firstly build a subfigure with multiple cats and dogs. Then, add a "felines" and "canines" undercaption. Finally, a under-undercaption with animals.

It is apparently not possible only with figure and subfigure environments. I utilize [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn) as compiler. They provide a richful documentation about graphical entities. Could you help me?

Comment: You don't need to “subcaption” each picture of a dog or of a cat, I guess, but only the group of dogs and the group of cats. Is this correct?

Comment: There is a subsubfigure setup in one of the answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423580/how-to-label-subset-of-figures-as-subfigures-and-include-an-overall-caption

Comment: I need to subcaption each animal individually, for example, with its owner's name or its specie.

Comment: If you don't need a figure or subfigure number, you don't need to use \caption at all.  \parbox or tabular will work fine.