# Subfigure: How to give caption two graphs of several subfigures?

Tags: subfloats

[image]

Hi all,

I would like to give b) and c) one caption together in addition to the captions they already have. And the same for d) and e).

Does anyone know how to do that?

So far, I use:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{....}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.49\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_1.png}
\caption{\small \centering \textmd{Baseline}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.49\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_2.jpg}
\caption*{\small \centering \textmd{}}\label{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_3.png}
\caption{\centering \small \textmd{Control group 2}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/cg3_women_4.png}
\caption{\centering \small \textmd{Control group 3}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.49\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_5.png}
\caption{\small \centering \textmd{Inclusion of dismissals}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.49\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_6.png}
\caption{\small \centering \textmd{Inclusion of all displacements}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption*{...}
\label{...}
\end{figure} \\
```

Comment: Welcome back to the site. Your question can be improved by making the document complete (like you did on your first question). This means adding the documentclass, the packages you use, and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. That is especially important here because there are different ways of setting up subfigures, and the solution to your current problem depends on which setup you have chosen.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423580/how-to-label-subset-of-figures-as-subfigures-and-include-an-overall-caption

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove `demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=bf,skip=0.25\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering\small

\caption{\dots} \label{fig:dots} % don't forget to supply suitable caption text

\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_1.png}
\caption{Baseline}
\end{subfigure}\hfill\null

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_3.png}
\caption{Control group 2}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/cg3_women_4.png}
\caption{Control group 3}
\end{subfigure}
Some words about subfigures b and c.

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_5.png}
\caption{Inclusion of dismissals}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/women_6.png}
\caption{Inclusion of all displacements}
\end{subfigure}
Some words about subfigures d and e.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```